# C Programming Negation: What is the difference between !string and !*string

Tags: c

A question regarding programming negation.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong:

- `!string` - checks if the char string is NULL;
- `!*string` - checks if the char string is pointing to something

Your explanations are appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

- `!string`: returns true if the `string` is pointing to NULL
- `!*string`: returns true if the first char in the string, that the `string` is pointing to is **== 0**

Answer (score 0):

In C, a string is a `0`-terminated array of characters.

If `string` is an array, it makes no sense to check `!string`, since it would always be false.

```
char string[100];
...
if (!string) // makes no sense
```

I assume `string` is a pointer that *points to* a string (to the first character thereof).

```
char* string;
...
if (!string) // makes perfect sense
```

`!string` means "`string` is a NULL pointer" (i.e. there is no character it points to; no string to work on).

`!*string` means "`string` points to a `\0` character" (i.e. to the string terminator; the length of the pointed-to string is zero).

Answer (score 0):

If `string` is `NULL`, it does not point anywhere.

If `string` does point somewhere, hopefully it points to an array of characters, terminated by a null byte.  It might point to a long string, like `"supercalafragalisticespialadocious"`, or it might point to a short string like `"hello"`, or it might point to a very short string like `"x"`, or it might point to the empty string, `""`.

When you're working with pointers, you have to be careful to distinguish between *the pointer* and *what it points to*.

Your variable `string` is a pointer.  And the expression `*string` refers to the first character pointed to by `string`.  If `string` points to `"supercalafragalisticespialadocious"`, then `*string` is the character `'s'`. If `string` points to `"hello"`, then `*string` is the character `'h'`.  And if `string` points to the empty string `""`, then `*string` is the null character `'\0'`.

So we have:

- the condition `if(string)` succeeds if `string` is nonzero, that is, if `string` is not the `NULL` pointer, that is, if `string` points somewhere
- the condition `if(!string)` succeeds if `string` is zero, that is, if `string` is the `NULL` pointer, that is, if `string` points nowhere
- the condition `if(*string)` succeeds if the character pointed to by `string` is nonzero, that is, if `string` is not an empty string
- the condition `if(!*string)` succeeds if the character pointed to by `string` is zero, that is, if `string` is an empty string

Finally, if `string` is a `NULL` pointer, then both `if(*string)` and `if(!*string)` are likely to crash, since they try to access the character pointed to by `string`, but a null pointer by definition points nowhere, so you can't fetch the pointed-to character to see if it's 0 or not.